# How to get the updated file back that posted to an api in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

**I need to send a .xml file to an API and in return the API will return the same file with some updations. How to get the file from the API in python?**

**I can able to send the file but stuck at getting the updated file back.**

```
import requests
import json
CLIENT_ID = "abcd"
CLIENT_SECRET = "ab342d"

grant_type = 'client_credentials'
body_params = {'grant_type' : grant_type}
# Getting the auth token
url='https://www.example.com/token'
response = requests.post(url, data=body_params, auth = (CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)) 
token_raw = json.loads(response.text)
token = token_raw["access_token"]

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token)}
url="https://some.api.abc.com"

# Posting the file 

req = {'file': open('report.xml', 'rb')}
res = requests.post(url, files=req, headers=headers)

# How to get the updated file from API
```

Any hints is highly appreciated, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

**test.py:**

```
from requests import Session

URL = "https://httpbin.org/xml"


def main():
    with Session() as s, open("test.xml", "w") as f:
        r = s.get(URL)
        f.write(r.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py
$ file test.xml 
test.xml: XML 1.0 document text
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my bad! i couldn't able to understand your code. If i stated my question right, i need to send a file to an api with authentication and get back the validated file

Comment: I just provided an example how to save a file from the request, you can adjust it to your needs.

Comment: sounds good, im literally new to requests library and python too. have couple of questions
1. per your knowledge what im doing for the authentication(am i using the auth tokens in a right way?) and posting the file to the api in above code looks good?]
2. Do i need to use the token while getting the file back? if yes what would be the syntax?
Please do help, thanks!